# Ошибка Class 'MySQLQuery' not found

Tags: php, laravel, классы, импорт

У меня есть класс SMSSender для отправки сообщений. Мне нужно сделать artisan команду, которая будет использовать класс SMSSender и отправлять смс пользователю. Класс SMSSender уже используется во многих местах. Но при использовании его в методе handle() artisan команды получаю ошибку **Class 'MySQLQuery' not found**, которая указывает на строку 37 класса SMSSender **self::$_instance->_database = MySQLQuery::instance();**. В этом классе используется множество других классов, и все они импортируются автоматически (если использовать класс SMSSender везде кроме класса артисан команды - ошибок не возникает). Почему возникает ошибка импорта в моем случае, если я использую класс SMSSender в artisan команде?

Comment: Возможно что у вас автозагрузка для веб-Laravel сделана по-другому и вы включаете этот файл напрямую, в то время как в artisan'е успользуется PSR автозагрузка, где ваш файл не указан.

Comment: казалось бы, при чем тут импорт...

Comment: Чтобы в артисан команде подгрузился класс я использую include_once и класс подключается, он заходит в метод instance() и там уже происходит ошибка что класса, который используется в этом методе нету. Если же использовать это вне артисан команды, то все работает

Comment: что значит импортируются автоматически? любой импорт происходит с помощью `use`. Если он не указан, а класс есть (такой пример может воспроизводиться в моделях), это потому что данный класс имеет такое же пространство имен. покажите строку `use pathto/MySQLQuery`.

Comment: MySQLQuery находится в том же пространстве имен что и SMSSender

Comment: да и на каком основании вы тогда используете include_once будуче используя ларавель, не для вывода шаблонов, а подключая классы?? Файлы классов и другие с использованием пространства имен не подключаются через include, второе если уже опускать лару правильно подключать через require! Всё в ларе подключается через use согласно стандарту psr-4. У вас и не будет ничего работать так.

Comment: Вы правы, но не понятно почему уже получив экземпляр класса, заходит в метод instance и уже там выходит ошибка, что класс не найден, хотя он находится в том же namespace...

Comment: И если из других мест создавать экземпляр, то все работает корректно, только в артисан команде так.

Comment: при подключении класса через include (require) вы получаете его, но в нём теряются все ссылки, так как внутри вы подключаете классы через use, а они уже не работают, так как по сути у вас получаются два `namespace`. грубо говоря include мерджит файл в один, просто возьмите и скопируйте код из класса в файл команды, это то что делает include. Почему в другом месте работает, я не берусь ответить, так как ваш код мне не известен.

Comment: хотя есть идея (первый коммент дает ответ) при include если использовать консоль root_path другой, а ларавель пытается подгрузить классы через автозагрузку, и их просто не находит (так как не определяет namespace, мой коммент выше)